# Constantes do CakePHP não são reconhecidas quando acesso arquivo no webroot

Tags: php, cakephp

Eu estava testando um sisteminha simples de upload no meu cakephp, pra isso, eu referenciei a pasta de imgs por esses caminhos que o index.php da pasta root me dá. Só que sempre estava dando erro, dizendo que o caminho da pasta estava errado, e quando dei um echo na variável, ao invés de me retornar `/var/www/html/app/webroot/`, estava me retornando `WWW_ROOT`. Nem o `. DS .` está funcionando. Ou seja, meu servidor não está reconhecendo as constantes do arquivo index.php na pasta webroot.

```
$uploaddir = WWW_ROOT;
$uploadfile = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . DS . $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Arquivo válido e enviado com sucesso.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possível ataque de upload de arquivo!\n";
}

echo 'Aqui está mais informações de debug:';
print_r($_FILES);
echo $uploaddir;
```

OBS: eu fiz 2 arquivos na própria pasta webroot, pra ter acesso direto, só pra fazer teste. Eu só queria saber, porque meu servidor não interpreta essa constante como ela tem que ser, tem algum acesso pra isso?

Answer (score 1):

Conforme você disse num comentário, seu arquivo está solto na *webroot* do projeto, por isso é acessado diretamente, sem passar pelo Cake. Dessa maneira, nada que é do Cake é inicializado, incluindo as constantes que você citou.

Veja as regras de reescrita de URL do apache que ficam no *webroot* do Cake (atenção aos comentários):

```
RewriteEngine On
# se o caminho corresponde a um diretório, acessa diretamente
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# se o caminho corresponde a um arquivo, acessa diretamente
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# caso contrário, chama o index.php passando o resto da URL como parâmetro
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Ou seja, o arquivo `index.php` do *webroot*, que é quem inicializa o Cake, só é chamado caso a URL não corresponda a um diretório ou arquivo físico abaixo do webroot.